# custom SKSpriteNode classes for use in .sks file?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ibinspectable

I'm making a custom `SKSpriteNode` Class, which I want to use in my `.sks` file. I want it to have `@IBInspectable` property. Is it possible? And how can I implement its `init(coder:)` method, or there is no need to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it's not possible to use `@IBInspectable`, that only works with classes in the storyboard editor.

you can create your custom class with an `init` and instantiate it from code. If you want to instatiate your custom object from the Scene editor you MUST use the `init(coder:)` func

you can have both init's in your class in case you wish to instantiate your object in code at some point as well as creating in a scene sks file.

```
init() {

    super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size, CGSize.zero)

    setup()
}

required init?(code aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(code: aDecoder)

    setup()
}

func setup() {
    //add some setup code here
}
```

Or if you ONLY want to instantiate the object in the scene file you can eliminate the normal init().